# Swift 2: Strange Objective C -> Swift method's signature conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a base class in Objective-C with the following method:

```
- (BOOL)canFinishWithError:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

when I try to override it in child class using Swift compiler forces me to declare this method without a return value:

```
override func canFinish() throws{
        // some code
        try super.canFinish()
    }
```

and not allows me to return something.

[image]

How can I return a value from this method? Is it a Swift 2/Xcode 7 beta issue and I should wait for release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s not a bug.

Swift 2 automatically recognizes method signatures which can be converted to use `try`.

A method returning `bool` and taking a pointer to a `NSError pointer` is automatically converted to a signature using `throw`.

You can learn more about that in this WWDC talk: (from 32:00) https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But in such a case what is a best way to return a Bool and an error if I really want to do so? In my case they are independent.

Comment: @Avt I don’t think it is possible. You could try wrapping the supercall in a `do/catch` and remove the `throws` but I doubt this will work.

Comment: @Avt Actually you might partly encounter a bug. A method with the signature `func canFinish() throws -> Bool` should be ok. The problem seems to be that you can’t override a Objective-C method that a signature like `- (BOOL)canFinishWithError:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error`.

Comment: Yes, if I remove `override` keyword code compiles but it is treated as a separate method.

Comment: If you want to turn this off, add the `NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW` macro to the ObjC declaration. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6